# not to pick date from datepicker if its age is low

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker which selects a date, but I need a date where the user cant selects the dates less than 22 years. means if the current date is 28/08/19 so user cant select the date like 28/8/18, 28/8/17, 28/8/16, 28/8/15

```
<input class="input--style-2 js-datepicker dob" type="text" placeholder="Birthdate" name="birthday" id="dob" value="">

<input class="input--style-2 js-datepicker dob" type="text" placeholder="Birthdate" name="birthday" id="dob" value="">
```

Comment: Use JS to work out the minimum date, then set the `min` property on the input. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#min

Comment: If you have jQuery datepicker (based on your tag) it has an option on `minDate`. https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: mmm... It would be a **maxDate**.... Try `maxDate: "28/8/1997"`... Please post your datePicker instantiation code if that comment does not already answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your intention, you need to use maxDate property of jQuery UI datepicker. This way, user can not enter a date which would result in him being less than 22 years old.

Initialization in jQuery would look like this:

```
$( ".dob" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: "-22y"
});
```

TimeFormat "-22y" equals to 22 years extracted from actual date.